# Default initialized boost::optional

Tags: c++, boost, option-type

Is there any way to default initialize a boost::optional variable without providing T's name?

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int a;
};

int main(){
    boost::optional<MyStruct> opt;
    opt = MyStruct(); // <--
}
```

My goal is to omit providing struct name when I just want to default initialize *opt*.

Answer (score 6):

If your compiler supports variadic templates and you are using Boost version 1.56 or higher, use [`emplace()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/reference/header__boost_optional_optional_hpp_/detailed_semantics.html#reference_optional_emplace) with no arguments:

```
opt.emplace();
```

If either of the conditions is not met (either a compiler without variadic templates or an older Boost) use `in_place` factory with no arguments:

```
opt = boost::in_place();
```

in Boost 1.59 you will be able to call 0-argument `emplace()` even in C++03 compilers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an in-place factory if you'd like to default initialize an optional value

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() {}
    int bar = 5;  
};

int
main()
{
    boost::optional<Foo> foo;
    assert(!foo);
    foo = boost::in_place();
    assert(foo);
}
```

[live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7506dafee5af62d6).

Comment: `boost::optional` now have `emplace()` member function (from 1.56.0). We should use it.